# Why is $w(t)t^{n}$ continuous for any positive function of exponential decay?

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on the above claim. I only think it holds for continuous functions $w(t)$. The book is here ; https://books.google.se/books?id=e_BjBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=lax+completeness+of+weighted+powers&source=bl&ots=rQCLmelCuX&sig=R5hWmqVTP8oRzMVaWUx60hUt5PA&hl=sv&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAWoVChMI2Z_8x8q6yAIVyJYsCh2MEgSG#v=onepage&q=lax%20completeness%20of%20weighted%20powers&f=false

As a counterexample consider $w(t)$ being 1 everywhere on some compact interval except at 1 where its zero and times $x^{1}$, this is not continuous. Is the formulation in the book wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: You are not missing anything, the book is wrong.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland wow...the great Lax falters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems not to be correct, the authour must have missed to add continous.